# Non-server side method of getting local IP address in browser?

Tags: ip-address

I am trying to provide a way for users on my LAN to "register" with the Network admin (me) without having to either a) host a page on my computer b) host a script on the central server (since it is only a router, not really a solid HTTP server) or c) sign up for a Dynamic Domain in order to either either of the first two and avoid the confusion of sending out a URL to a link to a local IP.

Is there a simple way to display the local IP address on screen via a client-side script? I'm thinking maybe I could have an iframe that points to some generic url with some javascript in the path, so that I can have the users go to a non-local site, and the iframe would pop up with their IP address that they can then enter into a form in the main remote page.

If all else fails, is there a way for them to look up their IP that is cross-platform and doesn't involve using the command line (I think the first, even if impossible, is probably more realistic than the second).

Comment: Looks like a system admin question to me - move to serverfault.com

Comment: It's only system admin until the need for javascript/iframes comes into it. Wasn't sure if that was their bag. But I'll give it a shot.

Answer (score 10):

Thankfully to Webrtc it is possible to access local IP from javascript.

Take a look at: http://net.ipcalf.com/ (source)

( It works in chrome )

However accessing local IP from Javascript could be a privacy and security issue.

and below simpler example then net.ipcalf.com

and on the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KdnGR/)

```
var RTCPeerConnection = window.webkitRTCPeerConnection || window.mozRTCPeerConnection;

var configuration = { "iceServers": [] };
var pc;
var localIP;

if(RTCPeerConnection){  

    pc = new RTCPeerConnection(configuration);
    pc.onicecandidate = function (evt) {  
        if (evt.candidate) { 
            if (!localIP) { 
                localIP = getIpFromString(  evt.candidate.candidate );
                console.log(localIP);
            }
        }
    };

     pc.createOffer(function (offerDesc) {;
        pc.setLocalDescription(offerDesc);                                      
    }, function (e) { console.warn("offer failed", e); });

    function getIpFromString(a)
    {
        var r = a.match(/\b(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\b/);
        return r[0];
    }

} else {
 //browser doesn't support webrtc   
}
```

Comment: How is this a privacy concern? The fact that so-and-so is at public ip A.B.C.D and local ip D.E.F.G is somehow more of an id then all the other things you can check about a user's machine? Or is it that you can then know their subnet and start scanning it even though you probably already know for the majority of users it's 192.168.x.y or 10.0.x.y etc.. where x = 0 or 1. Just curious if there's something I'm missing.

Comment: @gman 
Maybe I should remove word "huge" :) At the time is was answering the question I had some concerns about things like:
You can't hide your self by using different browser ( two browser will have the same local ip ) + a few more bits to fingerprint your browser. Enumering subnet, accessing router,printer other local devices and execute code through XSS - It is just another attack vector. Maybe also some issues with Timing attack.

Answer (score 1):

Yes there is actually. I think there is an example of what you are trying to do here: http://www.whatsmyip.org/more/

if you view source on that page you see the following for the internal ip section:

```
                            <p><b>Internal (LAN) IP</b>: <span id="localip">Checking...</span>
                        <script>
                            function MyAddress(IP)
                                { document.getElementById("localip").innerHTML = IP; } 
                        </script>
                        <applet code="MyAddress.class" MAYSCRIPT width=0 height=0>
                            Sorry You Need Java For This To Work
                        </applet>
```

So I'm thinking you have a couple of options, you can either download the copy of the compiled java applet on that site, or write your own. The general idea of how this works, is the java applets loads read the local ip, and then calls into the DOM and updates the innterHTML of that element. (btw, i'm not telling you to steal the applet, but it's a suggestion if you wanted to try it out for educational purposes)

Hope this helps.
Mark