# Internal IP Address Needed for Custom Server Application - PHP SERVER Variables

Tags: php, ip-address

I have read this:

[How to get the my system's IP address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4447716/how-to-get-the-my-systems-ip-address)

But it's not really getting at the root problem for me.  I need to get the client IP on an internal network, eg, something `192.168.1.7` so that I know if the server is being accessed from an internal location or not.

I'm updating some code that was built some time ago by someone else, and this code snippet is in there:

```
$octet = explode(".", getenv("REMOTE_ADDR"), 4);

if($octet[0] != 192 && $octet[1] != 168 && $octet[2] != 1) { 
    die("You are unable to view this page from your current location."); 
}
```

This looks like it's testing for that internal IP, but on another page with similar code, I get the `die` message.  That code actually shows my IP to be something other than `192.168.1.7`(this code's actually showing my static IP given to me by the ISP):

```
if($octet[0] != 192 && $octet[1] != 168 && $octet[2] != 1) { 
    die("You are unable to view this page from your current location: " . getenv("REMOTE_ADDR")); 
}
```

I'm a bit confused because this code seemed to have worked in the past but it isn't now.  I'm not totally sure when it stopped working but based on the code I'm seeing, it shouldn't have worked in the first place.

**NOTE**

I should also mention that all the clients needing access to this server are internal (mostly).  It's a CRM with a custom license key module.  I want these PHP pages to be accessible to only those clients on the `192.168.1.0` network.  But the tricky part is that there is a way to access the non-key system part of the CRM from outside using DNS at a location like this:

`crm.my-domain.com`

Suffice it to say that those clients accessing the CRM from outside the network, should not have access to the key module; only those clients on the `192.168.1.0` network should be able to see the keys.  So if I can get the internal IP I can test for it and show the page.

**NOTE 2**

I am running a DNS in the network and I have a portforward on the router to the server in question that is `<internal_ip>` on port `80`.

The DNS has an A record like this:

```
crm_servername    A    192.168.1.20
```

And it has a `CNAME` of this:

```
crm    CNAME    crm_servername.my-domain.com
```

Do I need more than this or should this work for me?  Currently I can access the server in question by the subdomain address but when I get to the pages in question, it still shows an external IP, `non-192.168.1.x`...

My question is, how to set up my DNS zone file such that when I am on the local network, and I go to a server on an IP such as 192.168.1.20, that I stay within the network and don't get routed out and then back in again?  It seems I'm going out and then in, from the ISP static IP, and the server thinks this.

Comment: Has something in your network setup changed? What is the IP of the server you are accessing? You are inside the internal network, right?

Comment: In addition to Pekka's questions, are you accessing the network from a VPN?  Some VPN configurations give a different IP address to connected clients.  E.g. the network for my company is `192.168.0.0` but our VPN connection assigns IPs like `10.167.111.0`

Comment: Yes, there have been some changes but instead of going through all that, I thought I would try to isolate it with a PHP question.  If I need to get into too much detail, I may have to ask another question elsewhere first...  I am inside a network, yes.  No VPN.  I'm on the same network as the server. Sorry for the vagueness.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could probably make this code work better if you change it to this:

```
function is_local($ip) {
    $octet = explode('.', $ip);

    return ($octet[0] == '10' ||
        ($octet[0] == '172' && ((int)$octet[1] >=16 && (int)$octet[1] <= 31)) ||
        ($octet[0] == '192' && $octet[1] == '168')
    );
}
```

This code will check if the IP address falls into any of the [private network](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_network) ranges which should mean your client is internal or connected through a VPN.

That may solve your issue, or it may be too broad.  If your IP is showing up as the one from your ISP, then somehow you aren't on the local network when you think you are or you're being port-forwarded into the internal network and therefore still show the remote IP address to the server.

Comment: This is a good point.  I think your code edit is too broad (since we are restricted to the `192.168.1.0` network), but your comment about the port forwarding may be helpful.  It almost seems like I'm not on the internal network, even though I really am...

Comment: Your function is also good.  On my test server, I've already written a similar function for the new code I'm writing.  If I can get passed this routing/IP issue, I will definitely use something like this.  Thanks!

Comment: On that note, if you access a script that contains `<?php var_dump($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);`  What is your result?

Comment: The only reason that I don't like checking for only 192.168 is because if your company ever changes their internal network (e.g. due to growth) or migrates the application to a system on another subnet, your code will fail until someone gets in there and fixes it.  This pretty much covers that so you don't have to upgrade it ever (until you use IPv6 ;)).  Internal is internal, if may somehow be a security breach if someone connects to your app via some other internal subnet, but that is an IT issue, not an application developer issue.

Comment: @nicorellius And in regards to my last comment, that is only a suggestion.  Obviously you or your managers may have reasons for doing it that way and that's fine, I'm just pointing out things to look out for in the future.

Comment: No, no, you are right.  It does cut down on code manipulation later.  I will definitely keep this in mind and probably implement it in my rebuild of this code.

Comment: drew010: the `var_dump` result:  `string(11) "<my_static_ip_from_isp>"`

Comment: So then I'm guessing you are getting that result when you access `crm.my-domain.com` (even if you are internal)?  It seems it must be going through a port-forward in the router otherwise I think you'd see the local IP.

Comment: Yes, there is a port-forward on the router that is running on port 80 for the server.  When I disable it, only the internal IPs can access the CRM.  This is not so bad, but the code is written in such a way that the subdomain is in the links.  Kind of a mess.  I thought I could patch it up with a better function but it looks like I will need to actually use relative paths to the links instead.  Thanks for all your help.

Comment: No problem, if you run your own internal DNS server, you can map crm.my-domain.com to an internal IP address when you are using the internal DNS server and it will map to the external IP when out of the company, but that means you have to have your internal clients using your internal DNS.  Anyway, glad to help hope you get it all solved.

Comment: Now that you mention it, you seem to know DNS and PHP well.  Could you assist further?  The reason I ask is because I am running a DNS server and that is part of the problem.  I'm still new to this stuff so that's why I'm here in the first place.  Sometimes these answers are helpful but don't quite get all the way to the root issue.  Would you mind one more piece of advice base don another edit of my question?

Comment: Do you have two DNS servers?  One external one for your domain and one internal one for your domain and systems?  Or is it one server handling both internal and external?  It's possible to do it either way.  It just sounds like the machine you are accessing from right now is getting the wrong IP address and is going through the port forward rather than just accessing the internal IP.

Comment: We use an external DNS service that handles the outside stuff and an internal server doing the internal stuff.  I've reviewed the DNS at the service and the zone files on the internal server but I'm not totally sure...

Comment: Double check the DNS settings of the internal machine, it seems like its just using the external DNS then.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/14651/discussion-between-nicorellius-and-drew010)

Answer (score 1):

You can not get that from Server variables because server has no way of knowing this information.

The only way is to interrogate the web browser (eg. by using a Java applet). However getting access to this information is unreliable at best.

See:

[Non-server side method of getting local IP address in browser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2138538/non-server-side-method-of-getting-local-ip-address-in-browser)

[Get the correct local IP address from java applet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1510526/get-the-correct-local-ip-adress-from-java-applet)

http://www.webdeveloper.com/forum/showthread.php?threadid=242538