# How to retrieve all the IPs from same machine using JS?

Tags: javascript, ip, ipconfig

The ipconfig command returns three IP address (same machine). Now I need to retrieve all these three IP address. The available api can only gives me one. Is there any way to find all these three IPs by using javascript? thanks!

Comment: I don't think you are suppose to have access to this in javascript, you can abuse `webRTC` to get the IP but that's a hack and should be fixed, checkout https://stackoverflow.com/a/19826403/3232170

Comment: @kigiri thanks but it does not work anymore.